# Why shows error whenever starting new session in Appium

Tags: session, android-emulator, appium

When I tried to start session this error showed up in my appium. The error message after I start session is like:

"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the log cat output."

So after this error there is no way to inspect the element as app screen is not showing in appium.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please recheck launch-able activity name, make sure it is correct.

Comment: Please edit this post and write the text of the errors inside your question so we can see it clearly.

Comment: Hello @MarcSances please check my Question now.

Comment: Hello, @AmitJain I hope you are talking about appActivity. But what to do if there's multiple appActivity

Comment: @AmitJain I changed the appActivity name. as reference I added a picture in post. Can you please check again.